# Show is a continuous linear operator

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis

I am reading the book introduction to functional analysis by Christian Clason. I need help with the problem 4.2 from the book:

Let $T:C[a, b] \rightarrow C[a, b],\ [Tx](t)=tx(t) \quad \forall t \in [a, b]$

1. Show T is a continuous linear operator
2. Calculate $\|T\|$
3. Show or give a counterexample for the closedness of ranT

What I have done:

1. (i) linear: $[T(\lambda x + y)](t) = t(\lambda x(t) + y(t)) = t\lambda x(t)+ ty(t) = [T(\lambda x)](t) + [Ty](t)$.

(ii) How can I show it is continuous. My idea was: Since $[a, b]$ is compact, it follows $x(a) \leq x(t) \leq x(b),\ \forall t \in [a, b]$. Take $x_0 \in C[a, b]$. $\forall \epsilon > 0 \exists \delta>0 : \|x - x_0\| < \delta \Rightarrow \|Tx(t) - Tx_0(t)\| = \|tx(t) - tx_0(t)\| = |t| \|x - x_0\| < |t| \delta = \epsilon$.

We can choose $\delta = \epsilon / |t|$. This proves T is continuous.

2. We know $\|T\| = \sup_{x \in C[a, b]} \frac{\|Tx\|}{\|x\|}$
   $\|Tx\| = \sup_{t \in [a, b]} |tx(t)| \leq \sup_{t \in [a, b]} |t|\|x\| \leq \sup_{t \in [a, b]}|t| |x(b)|$.
   Let $x(t) = 1 \in C[a, b]$, then $\|x\|=1$ and $\|Tx\| = \sup_{t \in [a, b]} |tx(t)| = \sup_{t \in [a, b]} |t|$

Is it correct what I have done so far?

3. I have no idea

Comment: The norm you are working with is the sup norm, right?

Comment: Also, you can show continuity by showing boundedness. Or are you unfamiliar with this equivalence?

Comment: @Keen-ameteur Yes, the norm I am working with is the sup norm
Yes, I also used the equivalence of boundedness to show continuity:
$\|Tx\| = \|tx(t)\| = |t| \|x(t)\| \leq |t| x(b) < \infty $

Comment: Hint for 3: $T$ is injective, so by open mapping theorem, if $ran(T)$ is closed then $T$ admits a bounded inverse (defined on the range). What is this inverse? Can it be bounded if $0 \in [a, b]$?

Comment: Concerning $3$ and the casel $0\in [a,b]$   show that $\sqrt{|t|}$ does not belong to the range but can be approximated by the elements in the range, by applying the Weierstrass approximation theorem or just by indicating the approximating sequence. For example if $a=0$ and $b=1$ you may take the MacLaurin series of $\sqrt{1-x}$ and plug in $x=1-t.$ In this way you may avoid applying advanced theorems.

Answer (score 0):

Assume $0\in [a,b].$ The range of $T$ consists of all functions of the form $tx(t),$ where $x\in C[a,b].$ On the other hand the closure of the range of $T$ consists of all functions in $C[a,b],$ which vanish at $t=0.$ Indeed, if $x(0)=0,$ then by the Weierstrass approximation theorem there exists a sequence of polynomials $q_n(t)$ such that $q_n(t)\rightrightarrows x(t).$ Then $p_n(t):=q_n(t)-q_n(0)\rightrightarrows x(t),$ and $p_n$ belong to the range of $T.$
Therefore the function $\sqrt{|t|}$ does not belong to the range of $T$ but belongs to the closure of the range.

**Remark** For $\sqrt{|t|}$ the sequence $p_n(t)$ can be indicated explicitly by applying the MacLaurin expansion of $\sqrt{1-u}.$